# Maven deploy:deploy-file publishes all files instead of one

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am building my Java application using Maven and the [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create an executable jar.

As a result, the target folder contains multiple jars and other files. However, I only want to deploy the executable jar file built via the Assembly Plugin.

To do this, I have tried to use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` and provided it with the following properties:

- file
- repositoryId
- url
- artifactId
- groupId
- version

However, when I execute the command, Maven deploys *all* files instead of only the executable jar.

I also tried disabling the default build step:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <!-- disable standard deploy -->
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The build part of my pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
  <build>
    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${BUILD_DATE}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>main.PAtrackMain</mainClass>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
              <Implementation-Build>${BUILD_DATE}</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <!-- disable standard deploy -->
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

How can I deploy **only** the executable jar without the other files?

Comment: You disabled the default deploy stuff, but did you try to use that instead? So that you just could do the `mvn deploy`. Instead of "detaching" the deploy plugin from any phase, you should try to attach the assembly plugin to the package phase. It has only one useful goal (`single`) so don't forget to specify that in the execution.
It's described quite useful on the "Usage" page of the plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is much simpler than you might think.
There are two kinds of artifacts, produced by maven project:

- main: `${artifactId}-${version}.${packaging}` - this one you would like to not publish
- supplemental: everything else produced by plugins (javadoc, sources, assembly, etc)

If project/module `packaging` is `pom`, that means following:

- project/module may not have main artifact, only supplemental ones
- some plugins are not enabled by default (https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-core/default-bindings.html - compare default bindings for `pom` and `jar` packaging)

Thus, all what you need is:

- switch module `packaging` from `jar` to `pom`
- enable missing plugins: `maven-compiler-plugin`, `maven-resources-plugin`, `maven-jar-plugin`, etc
- extra configuration of `maven-deploy-plugin` is not required