# Multimodule Spring project with Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

I am trying to build an app with multimodule architecture, where I have the following modules:

- app (with the controllers)
- persistence (where I keep all entities and repos)
- domain (pure Java-module)
- a parent module that combines all these modules, but it has no code, only the pom-file and properties.

How do I organize the project in order to have shared app-properties in the parent-module? And should the persistency module have spring-build plugin? Cause at the moment no module sees the properties of the parent.

Comment: Each module needs to know it’s parent, it is not enough for the parent to know it’s modules.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen they do, but still the application crashes, cause it can't find the properties.

Comment: Parent modules do not create jars so you need to put property files somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to force `pom`-module [to package artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334584/maven-deploydeploy-file-publishes-all-files-instead-of-one/73336084#73336084), in your case that would be something like:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>configs</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However in that case child modules inherit build configuration from parent, so you will need to disable configuration of `maven-jar-plugin` in child modules. It is better to create sibling module rather than solving maven puzzles.